# Convert nl string to vector or some numeric equivalent

Tags: javascript, string, nlp

I'm trying to convert a string to a numeric equivalent so I can train a neural-network to classify the strings. I tried the sum of the ascii values, but that just results in larger numbers vs smaller numbers.

For example, I could have a short string in german and it puts it into the english class because the english words that it has been trained with are short and numerically small.

I was looking into Google's word2vec, which seems like it should work. But I want to do this on the client-side. And I found a [node.js implementation, here](https://github.com/Planeshifter/node-word2vec), but that just runs the command-line tool.

How can I convert a string to something numeric, a vector perhaps in js?

Comment: Lookup "one hot encoding"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've considered assigning each new word you encounter an integer. You'll have to keep track somewhere, but that's one option.

You could also use whatever built-in hash method js has.

If you don't mind a few hash collisions, and the size of the resulting integers doesn't matter, may I recommend a trick I've used a few times before.

- Assign each letter [a prime number](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt) based on [its frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#/media/File:English_letter_frequency_(frequency).svg):

[image: Frequency of Letters in English]

So, `e = 2`, `t=3`, `a=5`, etc., which gives us:

```
2       e
3       t
5       a
7       o
11      i
13      n
17      s
19      h
23      r
29      d
31      l
37      c
41      u
43      m
47      w
53      f
59      g
61      y
67      p
71      b
73      v   
79      k
83      j
89      x
97      q
101     z
```

- Multiply the value corresponding with each letter in a word

So, `value` is `73*5*31*41*2`. `corresponding` is `37*7*23*23...`. Each unique set gives a unique answer. It collides for anagrams, so we've accidentally built an anagram detector.

There isn't really a linguistically sound way to do this, though. I suspect `word2vec` just assigns arbitrary integers to strings.