# proper algo to convert strings to integers while keeping semantic value

Tags: javascript, nlp

I've been trying to convert natural language strings into integers for use in a long short-term neural-network. I tried converting to binary, using a bag-of-words, and an associative-array with each letter corresponding to a prime-number.

I looked into Google's word2vec just to convert the words into word-vectors, but I'm looking for something I can implement in the browser. This is why I am looking for an algorithm that I can write in js.

I know there's node.js implementations of word2vec, but they just run word2vec in the command-line.

This is different than this question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29880071/3743069), that I asked earlier because I am looking for something that retains semantic meaning. I thought about using word similarity techniques, but didn't know how to implement resnik similarity in js.

I greatly appreciate any help or direction in converting nl sentences, or just the topic of them, to word-vectors or an array of ints.

Comment: Why not just using a map of words and their id, starting from id=1 and incrementing it for missed cases?

Comment: I've tried that, but the only meaning the words then have are the order they are in the map.

Comment: You need to have a look at Deep Net papers.